# How to combine moving cell + delete option in GMGridView for iphone app

Tags: ios5, edit, gmgridview

I want to combine moving cells & option to delete particular cell like iOS springboard in GMGridView. I can't understand how to combine those functionality so that user have option to move the cell across & if user wants to delete cell he has cross button.

Anybody knows about this?